# Is it possible to implement the factory pattern if the derived classes can make recursive calls to create other classes?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, pyqt5, factory-pattern

So I'm currently working on a GUI in PyQt5 and I'm creating a window based off of a yaml settings file that contains information about what widgets should be contained within the window and some of their attributes. I have implemented it using just a single class but am thinking of refactoring it to use the factory design pattern but the issue is that certain widgets are composed of other widgets (tabs, stacked widgets) and I make a recursive call when creating the tabs and stacked widgets.

So this is a minimal example of what I have:

```
class WindowCreator():
  def createWidget(self, parent, settings):
    if settings.type == 'tab':
      self.createTab(self, parent, settings)  
    if esttings.type == 'aTypeOfWidget':
      self.createATypeOfWidget(self, parent, settings)
    if settings.type == 'anotherTypeOfWidget':
      self.createAnotherTypeOfWidget(self, parent, settings)

  def createTab(self, parent, settings):
    # create tab elements
    for item in settings.items:
       self.createWidget(self, parent, settings)
```

What I thought of doing was creating a simple abstract class that would define a create method and then create subclasses of that for each of the components.

```
class Base():
  def create(parent, settings): ...

class Tab(Base):
  def create(parent, settings):
    #implementation that can call create for other derived classes
    CheckBox.create(parent, settings)
    #this is where I'm stuck

class CheckBox(Base):
  def create(parent, settings):
     #implementation that will only return a QCheckBox
```

Is there a way to do this within the factory design pattern? Or is there a better pattern that will keep the code cleaner?

Comment: What's the point of this? Qt already provides a [UI definition file format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-ui-file-format.html) for use with [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html), and PyQt provides the [pyuic tool](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) and [uic module](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/uic/uic-module.html) for working with them. There's really nothing to be gained from attempting to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: This allows the yaml to be altered and the window changes to match without having to manually update the UI.

Comment: That's exactly what Qt Designer does.

Comment: QtDesigner isn't an option. I need end users to be able to edit the yaml, it be as simple as possible and generate a window with the required elements. Having them edit .UI or worse actually using QtDesigner isn't an option. Trust me I wouldn't have opted for this approach if QtDesigner/UI was an option.

Comment: As I pointed out in my first comment, there's an existing tool-chain for converting Qt Designer files to PyQt modules. UI files are xml. There are dozens of tools available for converting xml to and from yaml (and many other formats). The UI file format is somewhat modular, so it isn't necessary to implement the whole specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider a combination of the **Factory** and **Builder** patterns. Create a factory class that creates a builder based on the data in the yaml file. You'll want to be sure that the possible controls specified in the yaml file are supported by your code and each control is represented by a corresponding builder.

To support a control hierarchy, there will need to be a distinction between controls that can have children. For example: a `QTabWidget` control could contain one to many tabs while a `QTLineEdit` would not contain children.

Create factories or builders for controls that do not contain children. Builders may still be a better option here if a control can be customized in certain ways such as color, position, size, and other attributes/properties.

Create builders for controls that could contain children for the minimum use case of adding child controls.

Example:

```py
    # ... parse yaml ...
    # assume 'yaml_data' is a dictionary of dictionaries:
    for root_control_data in yaml_data:
        # get builder class by root_control_data: container, tab, checkbox, etc.
        controlBuilder = ControlBuilderFactory.createBuilder(root_control_data)
    
        # build the control
        control = controlBuilder.build()
        # at this point the 'control' could be "fully formed" as a QT control.
```

The `ControlBuilderFactory` would return a concrete class implementing a `ControlBuilder` based on the control data provided. The concrete control builder encapsulates the details needed to create a corresponding QT control which may include using the `ControlBuilderFactory` to generate other control builders. This is when it is important to know whether a control supports children - a control builder shouldn't provide the ability to add children to controls that don't support children.

The **Composition Pattern** could also be applied. Create a `CompositeControl` that represents the control hierarchy within the yaml file and have a `render` method or similar to provide the QT control hierarchy.

Come up with rules about the yaml file such as how many root elements to support, how to define layout/gui composition, what controls and attributes to support, etc. This can help direct what features the control builders need to support.

You could also create an **Intermediary State**. Instead of parsing directly from yaml to QT controls, generate a class hierarchy that represents the target UI specified in yaml. Create a separate rendering mechanism to actual place controls into the UI using the intermediary state. This can provide opportunities and room to handle possible issues of error handling, malformed yaml, data sources, user input, etc.

I understand that you don't want to use QtDesigner and a suggestion has already been made to use that. From what I'm reading, sounds like QtDesigner has solved some of these problems so you may be able to look to that for answers/inspiration on how to design something that actually meets your needs.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. What sort of humanisms would make this more believably human to you?

Comment: If it's not AI generated, then good. If it is, please don't. That's all.

Comment: Metaomniliquant - @tchrist and I both have seen a *lot* of AI answers here, and (of course) even more answers written by us plain old humans ;-).  Sometimes, it's difficult to tell the difference.  One common pattern that we see, unfortunately, is folks that have "been away" for a while and not posted any answers, like yourself.  A lot of AI answers come from folks "returning" after an absence.  And, of course, there's absolutely nothing wrong with being away and returning -- We are glad to have you back!

Comment: And clearly, from your previous answers, you have the language skills and knowledge to answer these questions on your own, without AI assistance.  But @tchrist and I both saw something in one of your answers that a human also never does, but ChatGPT does quite frequently.  And "almost never" isn't "never", of course.  So it's entirely possible that you do that as a best practice when answering.  But I can completely sympathize with him thinking this might have been AI-based as a result.  As he said, if it's not, then all is good, and thanks for the feedback, fellow human ;-)

Comment: Again, "Welcome back" - Sorry it's been a bumpy landing.

Comment: Generative AI can indeed produce pain to platforms that depend on user-generated content. If the platform can't distinguish valuable content from not, that is a platform issue, not a user issue. It is disappointing to finally make the decision to start giving back and attempting to provide the value I've been receiving from the community for the past decade only to immediately, within hours, have it discredited. Thanks for the feedback nevertheless.

Comment: A contraindication  is that [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) would not misspell [Qt_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) and [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Or use sentence fragments.

Comment: This has given me some good ideas on how to proceed. Thank you.